# Very slow internet connection on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10-v1511

I have Windows 10 build 1511.

The internet connection is very slow.

I have a 30mbps internet connection.

I have 2 pc both wired connected with my router.

The first PC with Windows 7 has a very good connection. SpeedTest show 28-29mbps
The second pc , is a new pc , HP , with Windows 10. Speed test show 4-5mbps.

I've tried all network drivers version existing for this PC.

I've followed several suggestions found on internet like :

-Disable Windows Update Delivery

-Disable Windows update

-Quit Background Applications

But without success.

What can I do ?

Thank you !

Comment: Try booting into safe mode with networking and run the tests again.

Comment: It's the same situation.

Comment: Go to Network Setings -> Change adapter options -> Ethernet -> Status. What does "Speed" say?

Comment: The speed is 100mbps

Comment: But if I do speed test on speedtest.net , the download values is 4mbps

Comment: Are you sure that you are testing the same server on speedtest.net on both computers?

Comment: Have you swapped out the ethernet cable?

Comment: I'm testing the same server on speed test , on both computers. also I've made another test :  I have installed another hard drive on this Pc when I have installed Windows 7. When I boot into Windows 7 everything is OK. When I boot in Windows 10 I have the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

open a command prompt with administrator privileges and run the below command (copy and paste the whole line, then press Enter):

```
netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=normal
```

The mission should be accomplished :)